# Update Android App (Google Play) with new Flutter Apk

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I created an android app a year ago, i want to update it with a new apk version but built with flutter, is this possible? and how? thank you.

Comment: It is, as long as you use the same applicationId and the same keystore key to sign it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is completely possible. The three things you need to do:

1. Use the same package name (application id) as the old app
2. Sign the app with the same signing key as the old app (Google Play will do this for you if you use Google Play App signing)
3. Use a higher version code than your old APK version code.